# Did timezone() get any changes recently? Some of my code that used to work fine doesn't work anymore

Tags: python, python-3.x, timezone, pytz

I've written some code a while back (around April of 2021), and as I recall, the code worked exactly how I had wanted it. If you were wondering, the code is supposed to gather the hour, minute, second, along with the date and timezone, and display it every second.

```
from pytz import timezone
import datetime as dt
import os
import time

def local_time():

    def time_check(t):
        if t < 10:
            t = "0{}".format(t)
            
        return t

    p = dt.datetime.now()

    hour = time_check(p.hour)
    minute = time_check(p.minute)
    second = time_check(p.second)

    local_time = '{}:{}:{}'.format(hour, minute, second)
    return local_time

for i in range(999999999999999999999):
    time_zone = timezone(zone=None)
    print("Time: {} {}".format(local_time(), time_zone))
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system("cls")
```

The area that I've been getting errors at is `timezone(zone=None)` in line 33.
Is there a change with this function or am I missing something?

Comment: Why None for timezone? Also whatever you have written could be written in a line.

Comment: [Link to source](https://github.com/stub42/pytz/blob/82bb1b714af11f418def285b544b419775a36566/src/pytz/__init__.py#L130) - specifying `zone=None` --> `raise UnknownTimeZoneError(None)`

Comment: All you need is `datetime.now().strftime("Time: %H:%M:%S %Z")`

Comment: The December 2020 and February 2021 version/commit were the same - so it was like that in April 2021.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this instead

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
while True:
    print(datetime.now().astimezone().strftime("Time: %H:%M:%S %Z"))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I think I remembered that I used pytz to get around some bug with datetime, and completely forgot about the module and the datetime.now().astimezone() feature. Thank you!